# isHeadless for RNFirebase is always "undefined"

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, headless

I'm creating a feature for a React Native mobile app that performs an action whenever a FCM notification is received on the device. As part of this, I want to perform the action when the app is in the background and the notification is received - however I'm having some trouble understanding what's going on with the headless injection part of my app in order to get this to work on iOS. While the notifications are actually received by the device (even in background or quit state) and setMessageBackgroundHandler is executed most times (this is the main problem - I want to understand how it works so it runs every time), a console.log(isHeadless) in my AppWithHeadless ({isHeadless}) => { ... } ([based on Firebase Cloud Messaging docs](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#background-application-state)) returns "undefined" on initial mount and doesn't print afterwards at all (even when the setBackgroundMessageHandler works correctly).

I'm still learning React Native so any pointers here would help a ton - thanks!!

Here's my AppWithHeadless:

```
function AppWithHeadless({ isHeadless }) {
  console.log("isHeadless: ", isHeadless); // this prints undefined
  if (isHeadless) {
    // App has been launched in the background by iOS, ignore
    return null;
  }

  return (
        <App />
  );
}
```

Here's the summary of my AppDelegate.mm file:

```
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "RNFBMessagingModule.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

.
.
.


@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTAppSetupPrepareApp(application);

  RCTBridge *bridge = [self.reactDelegate createBridgeWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];

#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
  _contextContainer = std::make_shared<facebook::react::ContextContainer const>();
  _reactNativeConfig = std::make_shared<facebook::react::EmptyReactNativeConfig const>();
  _contextContainer->insert("ReactNativeConfig", _reactNativeConfig);
  _bridgeAdapter = [[RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter alloc] initWithBridge:bridge contextContainer:_contextContainer];
  bridge.surfacePresenter = _bridgeAdapter.surfacePresenter;
#endif

  if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
    [FIRApp configure];
  }

  NSDictionary *initProps = [self prepareInitialProps];
  NSDictionary *appProperties = [RNFBMessagingModule addCustomPropsToUserProps:nil withLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
  NSMutableDictionary *initialProps = [initProps mutableCopy];
  [initialProps addEntriesFromDictionary:appProperties];

.
.
.

- (NSDictionary *)prepareInitialProps
{
  NSMutableDictionary *initProps = [NSMutableDictionary new];

#ifdef RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
  initProps[kRNConcurrentRoot] = @([self concurrentRootEnabled]);
#endif

  return initProps;
}

.
.
.

@end
```